# How can I install a new font in PowerShell console?

Tags: windows, windows-8, powershell

I want to customize the look of the PowerShell in Windows. When I install new fonts, they work just fine, but I can't find them in PowerShell font selection (only default fonts are there).

Is there a way to install new fonts to PowerShell?

Comment: Just install the Terminal App from the Windows Store (the application is created by Microsoft) and change the appearance using the font you want, no need to modify the Registry.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [This article](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2009/07/24/windows-console-fonts/):

> Run regedit.exe and navigate to
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows
>   NT\CurrentVersion\Console\TrueTypeFont.
>
> Right-click in the panel on the right side and create a new string
>   value. Name that value “0″ or “00″ or however many zeros you need to
>   create a new key. That string’s value is the name of the font to add.

Comment: in my PC, `0` mean `Lucida Console`, `00` mean `Consolas`, I've tried to create `000` for `unifont-all` but it doesnt work. Do you have any clue about it?
I've got `unifont-all` from here : https://math.berkeley.edu/~serganov/ilyaz.org/software/fonts/

Answer (score 4):

Well PowerShell is a framework, so no you can't install a font to it.

I recommend you use the PowerShell ISE though. I think you'll like it:

[image: powershell ise fonts dialog]

Comment: Sorry I think I mean setting font for PowerShell console.

Answer (score 4):

Execute in PowerShell to set font for PowerShell.

`Fira code` is font name for example.

```powershell
Set-ItemProperty -Path "Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console" -Name "FaceName" -Value "Fira code" -Type String;
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a powershell script to add the information to the registry key:
https://gist.github.com/nathanverrilli/d3f12fbad87953e28aae78b5f191cdab

```
param (
    [string]$FontName,
    [string]$FontFile,
    [switch]$Help
);

function isAdminMode() {
    return ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] `
      [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent() `
    ).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)
}

####################################
# NULL comes in a number of shapes and forms in powershell 
function isNull($obj) {
    if ( ($obj -eq $null) -or
         (($obj -is [String]) -and ($obj -eq [String]::Empty)) -or
         ($obj -is [DBNull]) -or
         ($obj -is [System.Management.Automation.Language.NullString]) )
    { return $true; }   
    return $false;
}
####################################
function printHelp {
    
    write-host " "
    write-host "  Usage: $scriptName -FontName <fontname> -FontFile <truetypefontfile>"
    write-host "         add font <fontname> in <truetypefontfile> to console fonts registry key"
    write-host "         <truetypefontfile> must be present in system fonts directory"
    write-host "         Please note that only truetype (.ttf) fonts may be installed to the powershell terminal"
    write-host "         Please note that this script must be run with elevated permissions"
    write-host " "
    write-host "  Usage: $scriptName -Help"
    write-host "         print this message"
    write-host " "
    write-host "  Example: ./$scriptName 'Zen Mono Regular' -FontFile zenmono-r-6.1.3.ttg"
    write-host " "
    exit 0;
}
####################################

#the script name might be 'InstallConsoleFont' but it might have been changed, too
$scriptName = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name
$adminMode = isAdminMode

if (    ($Help) -or 
        (isNull($FontName)) -or
        (isNull($FontFile)) -or
        (-not $adminMode ) )    {   
    printHelp
}

$key = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Console\TrueTypeFont"

## Find out if $FontName is installed on the system
$fontFileName = join-path $env:windir "Fonts\$FontFile"
if(!(test-path $fontFileName))
{
        write-host "File $fontFileName is not present."
        write-host "Please check that the desired font is installed in a .TTF format"
        printHelp
        break
}
 
## Determine if $FontName is already installed as a command window font
$installed = get-itemproperty $key |
             get-member |
             where-object { $_.Name -match "^0+$" } |
             where-object { $_.Definition -match "$FontName" }
             
if($installed -ne $null)
{
    write-host "The $FontName font is already installed as a command window font"
    write-host "or another font is installed with that name ( $FontName )"
    write-host " "
    break
}
 
## Find out what the largest string of zeros is
$zeros = (get-itemproperty $key |
         get-member |
         where-object { $_.Name -match "^0+$" } |
         measure-object).Count
 
## Install the font
new-itemproperty $key -Name ("0" * ($zeros + 1)) -Type string -Value "$FontName"
write-host "$FontName font installed successfully as a command window font."
```

Comment: Please include a snippet of the code / reference rather than just a blind link.

Answer (score 2):

Windows console is very limited with features... Try console emulators [ConEmu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10904494/1405560) (I'm the author) or [Console2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/440370/1405560). Use of any font (proportional also), tabs, smooth window resize by mouse, user-friendly text selection, split-screen, jump lists, maximized/fullscreen, quake-style, transparency and much more.

Comment: Yeah I know. That's why I'm using PowerShell.

Comment: jsalonen: Maximus was referring to the Windows console, not the Windows Command Processor (cmd.exe). The PowerShell console host is just a regular console application and thus inherits the same limitations.