# PowerShell 5.1 Console, using Powerline fonts and Starship

Tags: powershell, fonts, truetype-fonts, fontconfig, starship

I wanted to try and resurrect a question from a few years back. There are a few speculative comments on there that this *might* not work, but I have a feeling that there are dozens / hundreds of geniuses on here that have cracked this with ease and right now have Starship with Powerline fonts on their normal PS 5.1 console (i.e. **not** Windows Terminal). 2 years and 4 months on from that question, I'd really appreciate if someone has a solution to this ... (I would note that in my work environment, on Server 2012 / 2016 environments, I will be using PS 5.1 consoles for at least the next 4-5 years, and while it's far from a critical thing, it's nice to try and build a comfortable/functional environment). *Note that this is specifically **not** a question about Windows Terminal.*

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62113888/starship-symbols-in-powershell

Comment: You might be able to use [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/502345/8672). Your font must be installed.

Comment: There is no conclusive answer on this @Ramhound, just a few people making some random speculation that is *might* not be possible. Just because they said "this is not possible" is not a statement of fact, just a statement of opinion. Can you point to a categorical proof that this does not work? About where the question is, I just look on SuperUser and StackOverflow as essentially the same in terms of overlap of ideas and information (the question was on StackOverflow, a part of StackExchange, and is linked to in the OP).

Comment: Thanks @harrymc, you might be onto something there. I think I will have a good root around in this area over the next few days, try to enable TrueType fonts in the 5.1 PowerShell/cmd console, and then see if I can get Powerline fonts to work via that route. 

Comment: I did link to it, just checked again, the link was in the OP at all times, from when I posted it(!). I agree that the it's limited / Microsoft have let that console (and PS 5.1 itself) stagnate, which is a real shame, as it's still the default PowerShell on Win 10 *and* Win 11. Being the default, we will be have to contend with that console version and that version of PS for many years to come (sadly, I'd much rather that PS 7.x was the standard on Win 11).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows default console (conhost.exe) just does not support printing all Unicode characters. For example, each buffer Cell is limited to [16 bits of character data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47852866/7411885). The issue is not (only) with the font or encoding

Here's some random characters that work fine:

```
« »
ᐊ ᐅ
҂ ҈
```

You can generate the full list with something like this, and see which codes render in your font:

```
0x20..0x1600 | %{[pscustomobject]@{code=$_;char=[char]$_}}

code char
---- ----
  32
  33    !
  34    "
  35    #
  36    $
  37    %
  38    &
  39    '
```

Everything else about starship seems to work fine in the 5.1 terminal